# Generating nuget-packages for Octopus Deploy and Azure Cloud Services

Tags: azure-web-roles, octopus-deploy

I've been trying for a week to deploy a webrole to Azure Clous Services without quite getting there.

Here is my setup:

I've got a cloud solution with a cloud project and a MVC application (standard no changes to template yet). Its under source control in Visual Studio Online.
I'm using octopack to try generating the nuget package
I'm using the buildt in nuget repo from Octopus
The Octopus server and tentacle is hosted on a VM in azure
I've created a step-template for my deployment step (see this [article](http://www.henrihietala.fi/how-to-deploy-azure-cloud-services-using-octopus-deploy/))

My plan:

I'd like to have a CI build to a dev-service and a seperate build to push my project to the staging environment and roll it onto the production environment using Octopus.

My problem:
The packages that are produced by Octopack seems to not contain what they should. And I've tried to play around with the nuspec file included in my webrole to get it just right. Something ends up missing either way i try.
Have anyone gotten this to work? I'd appreciate any tips pointing me in the right direction as I've slowly been running out of ideas. So i turn to you my fellow nerdlings for some much needed help.

Regards 
ZiGGstern

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it *looks* like you're in need of the octo.exe to automate deployments after build within Visual Studio/TFS Online to your target environments.
I'm trying to focus on this statement:

> I'd like to have a CI build to a dev-service and a seperate build to
>   push my project to the staging environment and roll it onto the
>   production environment using Octopus.

You can configure within your build-template, using the "Post-Deploy Script Path" a PowerShell script to call the Octo.exe (with an API Key) and fire off a deployment for your desired environment(s). You can customize this per build if you so choose. I've used this method by creating a folder within the root of my Solution (I call it 'Tools' but the name doesn't matter). Within that Tools folder, I add a PowerShell script AND the octo.exe. The PS script fires the Octo.exe which makes a call to my Octopus Server and with the "create release" option, I'm able to automatically deploy to whatever environment AFTER my build finishes within TFS. Make sure to always include those files (right-click in VS and in file properties select 'always copy').

I'm not quite sure why your NuGet packages would not be configured correctly, but that should be remedied first. Your question is trying to ask for two things and it's not clear which is more important to you; NuGet package or the Deployment from CI build. Having said that, I think you need to give more details on why you think your NuGet package is inadequate or not working correctly for your Azure services.

Please note, the site you supplied is using a custom PowerShell script in the form of a step template. It may be best to try the default Azure step within Octopus first *before* using a customized script. Just a thought.

Read more about the Octo.exe here: http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=360596

Comment: Thanks for your tips, ill take a look at it and check if it helps me. :)

Comment: Quick question for you. What should the nuget packet contain?

Comment: Well, it depends. It *should* be the final, compiled contents of your WebSite, or dlls for Services and such. Getting the content of your packages should be done first because if you don't get everything in the correct location, manipulating the content becomes a hassle - it's best to get this properly done through the NuSpec file.

Comment: Thx for taking the time to help. Thats exactly where i've been having problems. I know i need the cspkg, csdef and cscfg files as well as the dlls from the project. If i've understood this correctly i get the website/content files in the cspkg file. However im not able at the moment to get the cspkg file out of the build so i end up trying to create it on the octoserver after the fact. I think this might be the core of my problem.

Comment: Trying to "create" anything on the Octopus Server is a bad idea. You want the Octopus Server to deal with configuration *alterations* - different environments different settings. I'd focus your efforts FIRST on the NuGet package, then get to the deployment aspect with the Octopus Azure step.